# Can't determine if a branch has been merged when squash is used

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

My team uses github and sourcetree to manage our workflow. We've recently started trying out github's squash merge feature. We really like how it keeps our work history tidy, and essentially has a single commit per PR.

One of the unexpected downsides of using squash commits is that it's difficult to tell when a local branch can be deleted. My entire team seems to manage their local branches based on being able to visually see in the commit graph that it's been merged, and every few days we'll go through our local branches one by one seeing if they've been merged, and then remove it locally if it has. Enabling squash merging removes this visualization and makes it difficult for us to tell if the branch has been merged.

We'd really like to use the squash commit feature, but we need a reliable way to determine if a branch has been merged and is safe to be deleted locally. Are there any good ways that we haven't thought of to achieve this?

Comment: If you have a access to a shell, you could `git diff <feature_branch/HEAD> <merge_commit>`.  Or if you can't tell which commit is the merge, maybe `git checkout <feature_branch>; git rebase origin/master; git diff HEAD origin/master`

Comment: Do github and sourcetree not offer the `--first-parent` option?  Linearized histories can be easier to look at but they'd be more accurately spelled "lobotomized".  Sometimes that's all you need, but it's a limiting as a way of life.

Comment: @0x5453 running git commands for each branch doesn't seem like a very scalable solution. We'd have to create a script or something to iterate through all the local branches and delete the ones that were merged. That might be something that could work.

jthill I don't believe that they do.

Answer (score 4):

> My entire team seems to manage their local branches based on being able to visually see in the commit graph that it's been merged,

This seems to be the actual problem right here.  If you're already using a GitHub pull-request workflow, the status of the pull request should be the authoritative answer to this question.  Has the PR been accepted?  Good!  Branch is merged, move on with your life.

---

One option you may want to consider is adopting (and possibly enforcing) a workflow in which you only accept single-commit pull requests.  Let people do whatever the heck they want in their local repositories, but when submitting a pull request they squash the appropriate commits together before submitting (and make liberal use of a rebase workflow locally to update the pull request if they need to make changes).

This has the advantage that the "visual inspection" method will continue to work, since you will no longer be synthesizing commits on GitHub.

---

**Update**

I've put together [a small tool](https://github.com/larsks/github-tools/blob/master/git-is-merged) that uses the GitHub API to determine if pull requests associated with a given commit sha have been closed.  Drop the `git-is-merged` script into your `$PATH` somewhere, and then you can do this:

```
$ git checkout my-feature-branch
$ git is-merged
All pull requests for 219e0f04a44053633abc947ce2b9d700156de978 are closed.
```

Or:

```
$ git is-merged my-feature-branch
All pull requests for 219e0f04a44053633abc947ce2b9d700156de978 are closed.
```

The script returns status text and exit codes for:

- No pull requests exist
- All pull requests are closed
- Some pull requests are closed
- All pull requests are open

For squashed commits, you can use any of the commit shas that were part of the original pull request *or* the commit sha of the squashed commit.

As written this tool will only work with public repositories, but it's using the `PyGithub` module which does support authentication.

Comment: So the problem is that it's difficult to manage whether or not a PR has been accepted. People don't immediately delete their local branch once a PR has been merged. Yes on Github it's easy to match a PR to a branch, but a week after a PR has been merged, and I have 12 local branches that potentially need to be deleted, it's a pain in the butt matching a local branch to it's PR in github, and confirming merger so that it can be deleted.

Single commit pull requests is an interesting idea, but it becomes difficult to enforce when changes are requested on a given PR.

Comment: See my update on a solution that takes advantage of the GitHub API to answer the question.